# Next without For error?

Tags: vba, excel

I have lots of data (numbers) with heading in several worksheets that I am trying to zero. This is done on each column as follows: Taking the value of the first row in the column and subtracting this value from all rows in the column.

I have put together this code (may not be the best way, but Im new to VBA so :))

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Header As Range, ColData As Range
Dim firstrow As Long
Dim cell As Range, cell2 As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set Header = ws.Range("B5").End(xlToRight)

For Each cell In Header
    If IsEmpty(cell) Then
    Else
        firstrow = cell.Offset(2).Value
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Offset(2)) Then
            Set ColData = ws.Range(cell.Offset(2), cell.Offset(2).End(xlDown))
            For Each cell2 In ColData
                cell2.Value = cell2.Value - firstrow
            Next cell2
 Next cell
```

I am getting the error of Next without For? Am I missing something? forgive me if its something stupid I have checked several times and cant seem to spot it!

Thanks!

EDIT: Fixed IsEmpty function and it ran.. not giving the correct output yet but I'll work on it!

Comment: you are missing two `End If` 's

Comment: Fixed it and still getting error as I have said in the comment below!

Comment: Thanks and welcome to SO. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment to your question, you are missing two `End If` statements. Here is a simple way how you can avoid this kind of problem when typing out your code:

Every time you start an `IF _condition_ Then` statement, immediately hit Enter twice and type the `End If` line. Then go up one line and type what goes inside the IF statement.

The same technique can be applied to all languages and statements that have an opening and a closing marker (For/Next, etc.), be it a keyword, a pair of brackets `{} [] ()`, or comment marks `/* [...] */`.

Comment: Take a look at my edited code, still get an error.. Error says Run-time error 438, object doesnt support this property or method :(

Comment: @MofasaE Please start a new question instead of asking another question here.